# Will WIndows 8 be a Problem?

Tags: windows-8

I am in need a of a new laptop soon and most of them for sale look to have Windows 8 on them. I would like to just wipe it off and install Ubuntu 12.10 on the laptop. Will the Win8 secure boot stuff be a problem for me at all? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Whether you wish to continue buying that laptop or not - I would recommend reading this question - [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/114818) to be prepared for stuff you would likely encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 itself won't really be a problem, but the secure-boot stuff that is included on all windows 8 computers probably will be.  You will want to investigate the hardware manufacturer and the specific hardware model to see if they either allow turning off secure-boot, or if there is some way to install/boot a different OS.   The Ubuntu 64-bit installer supports UEFI booting, so getting it installed is the only real hard part.

Please do read the link that Aditya posted for more information: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)